# SyntaxError: Unexpected token h in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse: mean stack

Tags: angular, express, ionic3, httprequest, mean-stack

This is my ionic code

```
dialogflow(question) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/dialogflow',question,{headers: headers})
    .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

In the console log I'm getting errors as

> POST http://localhost:3000/api/dialogflow 400 (Bad Request)
>   This is from routes files(back-end)

```
router.post('/dialogflow', function(req,res) {
  console.log('reached here');
```

In the back-end(mean) console it is throwing an error as

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token h in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at createStrictSyntaxError (D:\product\project-1\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:158:10)
    at parse (D:\product\project-1\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:83:15)
    at D:\product\project-1\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:121:18
    at invokeCallback (D:\product\project-1\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)
    at done (D:\product\project-1\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:213:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (D:\product\project-1\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:273:7)
    at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: How does your __question__ object look like?

Comment: it's not an object it's just a string. Now I have converted it in to the object it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

The object being sent is not correctly serialized.

```
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at createStrictSyntaxError (D:\product\project-1\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:158:10)
at parse (D:\product\project-1\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:83:15)
```